# How can I reliably tell if a particular object is a Meteor Collection object (on the client side)

Tags: meteor

I have a function that receives a Meteor Collection object (that generated by `new Meteor.Collection("lol_cats")`)

How do I reliably tell whether any particular object is such a Meteor Collection object or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Javascript's `instanceof` operator: `if (x instanceof Meteor.Collection)`.